# Failed to schedule core-dns on fargate: timed out while waiting for "coredns" to be scheduled on Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-fargate, coredns

I'm following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/getting-started-eksctl.html) doc to create an EKS cluster with the below command:

`eksctl create cluster --name my-cluster --region ap-south-1 --fargate`

While trying to create an cluster with eksctl, it's giving me this error after about 30 mins:

```
2023-08-21 01:05:46 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-eks-sample-cluster2-cluster"
2023-08-21 01:06:46 [ℹ]  waiting for CloudFormation stack "eksctl-eks-sample-cluster2-cluster"
2023-08-21 01:08:49 [ℹ]  creating Fargate profile "fp-default" on EKS cluster "eks-sample-cluster2"
2023-08-21 01:11:00 [ℹ]  created Fargate profile "fp-default" on EKS cluster "eks-sample-cluster2"
2023-08-21 01:11:31 [ℹ]  "coredns" is now schedulable onto Fargate
2023-08-21 01:36:33 [!]  1 error(s) occurred and cluster hasn't been created properly, you may wish to check CloudFormation console
2023-08-21 01:36:33 [ℹ]  to cleanup resources, run 'eksctl delete cluster --region=ap-south-1 --name=eks-sample-cluster2'
2023-08-21 01:36:33 [✖]  failed to schedule core-dns on fargate: timed out while waiting for "coredns" to be scheduled on Fargate
```

Tried extending the timeout but still it's the same. Also tried without `--fargate`, no use.

Tried setting --vpc-private-subnets option, no use.

When checking on the CloudFormation Stack, no Nodes are created in the CoreDNS section it says 'No nodes setup to schedule pods'.

But in the documentation, it says everything will get created and configured automatically.

Is it because I configured eksctl with root user credentials?

Can anyone please help me on resolving this?

Comment: It could be a race condition. eksctl has to wait until the Fargate profile it deploys CoreDNS. Look to see whether the Fargate profile is created and if kube-system is listed in the namespaces section of the Fargate profile. If it is, try creating the cluster again. It could be a temporary issue.

Comment: default and kube-system are listed in the namespaces of the Fargate profile. But still, it's the same issue when I'm trying to create the cluster again with the same command. Tried giving a new name to the cluster too.

Comment: Verify you're using the latest version of eksctl. If you are, consider opening a case with support.

Comment: My aws-cli and eksctl are configured with my root user credentials. And I haven't added any roles in the IAM for the root user assuming that the root user already has all the permissions. Can that be an issue?

Comment: Tried with a new user with all the required permissions. Still, the same is the issue. Is it because my AWS account is on the free tier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was with my AWS account. It was in the Basic Plan and the Free Tier was over which I presume is what has blocked it from creating Nodes.

I created a new AWS account and when tried with it, this worked well.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. That's a hard one to troubleshoot unless you're looking at the billing reports.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the support @JeremyCowan :-) It would've been better if ekctl responded with a proper message so that the users could get pointed in the right direction for troubleshooting.